# How to identify this process

Tags: process

In the background, there is a process taking up a lot of processing power. Htop says it's using a whole core. (Of my quad core)

It's strange because I have no windows open. How do I identify the greedy process so that I can kill it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for the PID of the process and then `ls -l /proc/<pid>/exe`.
This tell you the name of the binary that's executed.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but I think BUM software package can help you deal with your problem. Install bum using this code in a terminal window:

```
  sudo apt-get install bum
```

Once you're finished you can use BUM right away (it requires administrative privilegies to be run), and you will be able to see a long list of active and inactive processes/apps in the list provided by BUM. To be able to learn more about a specific process/application press the ADVANCED button located in the low-left corner of BUM's window. You can uncheck, check or recheck processes and apps from that list (enable, disable, reenable them), and stop anything you consider to be either suspicious or completely useless for your needs. When you are finished, press APPLY to modify your system settings.

Be aware that you can harm your system if you don't pay attention to all the processes/apps that you want to stop for good, and it is always a good idea to test them one by one, and not a whole bunch of them at once. If in trouble, boot into recovery mode, login, open BUM and reenable one or more esssential process(s) that you previously disabled in a hurry.